# applying for a uk visa with Italian residence permit card

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, italian-residents

I am an Indian passport holder and I have an italian residence permit card which is going to be expire on the 25th of September. No doubt I am going to renew my documents but I want to visit the UK for few a days in this July. Can I apply for a visa with validation of 3 months or less of residence permit card?

Answer (score 1):

UK Immigration Rules do not specify a minimum validity period for residence permits. The eligibility requirement is to be able to show ties to your country of residence that demonstrate you have a compelling reason to leave at the end of your planned visit eg job, family, savings.

So yes, you can apply.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules